# update glib-1.2 project to use glib2

Tags: glib, autoconf

I'm resurrecting an old open source project that uses glib-1.2. I figure one of the things I should do is update it to use glib2-2.34, but I can't find any documentation on doing that. In particular, I would like to know the changes I need to make to my autoconf setup, currently

```
configure.ac:AM_PATH_GLIB(1.2.0)

src/Makefile.am:AM_CPPFLAGS = @GLIB_CFLAGS@
src/Makefile.am:arccc_LDADD = @GLIB_LIBS@
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found after looking through open source projects for examples: replace the above lines with

```
configure.ac:PKG_CHECK_MODULES([DEPS], [glib-2.0 >= 2.34.3])

src/Makefile.am:AM_CPPFLAGS = @DEPS_CFLAGS@
src/Makefile.am:arccc_LDADD = @DEPS_LIBS@
```

Also, I decided to move the entire project to `cmake`, and can recommend that route.

Comment: The whole GNOME stack is one of the better Autotools-based projects and I experienced a lot of pain using CMake for a GLib/GObject project I am working on. So, although initially it might be easier to go CMake, I cannot recommend it once you incorporate things like gtk-doc, GObject Introspection and the like.

Comment: this is not a gnome- or even gobject-based project, it just happens to be using glib as a datastructure library.